# ios vertical swipe between views

Tags: ios, draggable, drag

I'm basically trying to achieve this effect.

[image]

I'm not interested in the folding effect as I have something similar but in how to drag the navigation controller to switch to another view witch is an UITableView. In other words, how to switch vertically to anther view by dragging the navigation controller
Any ideas are very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try to replace the transition animation of `layer` of the `view` of `UINavigationController` class. it might help you, I'm always using this way to do the custom animations.